# django-compressor and data-URIs

Tags: django, django-compressor

I've got [django-compressor](https://github.com/mintchaos/django_compressor) up and running, and have tested with COMPRESS_OFFLINE both on and off (both work). Now I am trying to use its CSS data-uri generation capability but am not having much luck. The otherwise excellent documentation doesn't say anything about how to configure or use it, other than to add the setting:

```
COMPRESS_CSS_FILTERS = [
    'compressor.filters.css_default.CssAbsoluteFilter',
    'compressor.filters.datauri.CssDataUriFilter'
    ]
```

If I then link to a stylesheet that includes something like:

```
p.imagetest {
  background: url(/static/img/foo.jpg);
  height: 100px;
}
```

and view source on that stylesheet, I expect to see the image represented as a data-uri, but I don't - it's still the normal path/to/file.

If I set `COMPRESS_OFFLINE` to true and run `manage.py compress` and inspect the generated file, same deal.

Is there an additional step required to get data-uris generated in stylesheets with django-compressor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem may be referring to file size.

> django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_DATA_URI_MAX_SIZE
>
> Only files that are smaller than this in bytes value will be embedded.

By default `COMPRESS_DATA_URI_MAX_SIZE` is set to 1024 bytes.
So you need to increase this value to allow the file to be encoded.

Comment: Bingo, that was totally it - thanks. 1024 seems like a ridiculously small default value.